# Json Error In Laravel Ajax

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, crud

I'm Use Laravel 5.2 And Ajax For Crud
Insert to Database is Correct But When Laravel Response The Browser Show Below Error In Console

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Laravel Code:

```
return response()->json('ok');
```

Jquery Code:

```
    $.ajax({             
type: type,             
url: my_url,             
data: formData,             
dataType: 'json',             
success: function (data) {
....
error: function(data){// Error...                 
var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);                 console.log(errors);                 
$.each(errors, function(index, value) {                     $.gritter.add({                         
title: 'Error',                         
text: value                     
});                 
});             
}
```

RedyState=4
Staus = 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you paste your all controller code related to this error? Make sure you're not echoing anything before returning json response.

For example,

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    echo "hi";
    return response()->json('ok'); 
});
```

It would cause parse error.

Comment: YES!! Solved...Before respnce() I Use echo()

Answer (score 0):

With the Json response, what if you try something like.

```
return response()->json(['status'=>'ok']);
```

Comment: Ok so what does your output look like. Can you post that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You javascript code should be

```
$.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: my_url,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function (xhr){
        var data = xhr.data;
    },
    error: function (error){

    }
});
```

And why are you using `var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);` ? Your response will be always json, no?